# How to debug a child process from fork() using android_server from IDA?

Tags: android, fork, remote-debugging, ida

I'm debugging a .so in an Android app using android_server from IDA.

The parent process creates a child process with fork(), and those 2 processes communicate with each other by pipe(), shown in the following figure:

**The fork and pip function**

[image]

**The result of this fork**

[image]

My question is:
How to debug the child process with android_server?

I have tried this:
Run this application 2 times and force the second one to go to the child branch, but I fail to run the same app for 2 times.

Thank all the people who wants to help me.